# Unknown table 'translated_words' in information_schema

Tags: php, mysql, sql

имеется код на PHP, который показывает все содержимое таблицы бд

```
   <?php

$response = array();

require 'db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM translated_words") or die(mysqli_error($con));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product = array();
        $product["word"] = $row["wprd"];
        $product["word"] = $row["word"];
        $product["wordRussian"] = $row["wordRussian"];
        $product["defenitionRussian"] = $row["defenitionRussian"];
        $product["defenitionEnglish"] = $row["defenitionEnglish"];
        $product["wordChina"] = $row["wordChina"];
        $product["defenitionChina"] = $row["defenitionChina"];
        $product["wordJapan"] = $row["wordJapan"];
        $product["defenitionJapan"] = $row["defenitionJapan"];

        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

После попытки вывести все из таблицы, таким образом, описанном выше, PHP ругается и говорит Unknown table 'translated_words' in information_schema. В чем может быть проблема?

P.S db_connect.php

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {


    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect() {
        require 'db_config.php';

        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());

        $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

        return $con;
    }

    function close() {
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());
     mysqli_close($con);
    }

}

?>
```

P.S.S db_config.php

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER' , "localhost");
define('DB_USER' , "id8239005_pkorotaev");
define('DB_PASSWORD' , "pavel2002");
define('DB_DATABASE' , "id8239005_words");
?>
```

Comment: А где вы выбрали базу данных в вашем коде? Вы произвели только подключение к серверу. Естественно, при таком раскладе сервер будет что-то пытаться найти в служебных базах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли использовать класс осуществляющий подключение к базе данных.

```
$response = array();

require 'db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *FROM translated_words") or die(mysqli_error($db));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product = array();
        $product["word"] = $row["wprd"];
        $product["word"] = $row["word"];
        $product["wordRussian"] = $row["wordRussian"];
        $product["defenitionRussian"] = $row["defenitionRussian"];
        $product["defenitionEnglish"] = $row["defenitionEnglish"];
        $product["wordChina"] = $row["wordChina"];
        $product["defenitionChina"] = $row["defenitionChina"];
        $product["wordJapan"] = $row["wordJapan"];
        $product["defenitionJapan"] = $row["defenitionJapan"];

        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

db_connect.php:

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {


    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect() {
        require 'db_config.php';

        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

        return $con;
    }

    function close() {
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());
     mysqli_close($con);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Прощу прощения, привел не весь код, в коде php связывается с другим файлом, где и прописаны эти переменные как константы, привести код целиком?

Comment: @ПавелКоротаев из того что вы предоставили не видно где происходит подключение к базе данных. И зачем вам переменная `$db` если все соединения у вас через переменную `$con`? Предоставьте листинг **db_connect.php**.

Comment: предоставил в запросе

Comment: @ПавелКоротаев вставьте это в вопрос.

Comment: прощу прощения, вставил

Comment: @ПавелКоротаев ответ исправил.